# $regex working differently with find() and update() mongoose

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

I have following regex for finding links in text snippets.

```
var searchQuery = /(^|\s|\n|>)(ftp|http[s]?):\/\/.*/gm;
```

When i use this in find(), i get say 11 matches:

```
Table.find({ text : { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'xi' }})
```

But when i use this with update(), i get only 1 match:

```
Table.update({ text : { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'xi' }},
{$set: {tags: 'bookmark'}})
```

Can someone point out what is the difference in the usage of regex(if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `update` to apply to more than just the *first* match you need to supply the `{multi: true}` option.

```
Table.update({text: { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'xi' }},
             {$set: {tags: 'bookmark'}},
             {multi: true})
```

Comment: I guess that's what is missing. Will try it by tomo.